# Derived class object assigned to Base class variable

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Below code, A is base class and B is a derived class. When I do `A a1 = new B();` and call what a1 can see, I see that it can only see class A field because a1 is of A type so it can not see B specific members and this is what I expected too. But when I call a1.Display() it prints out B's display method. How come a1 can not see B field but can reach B's display method?

```
using System;    

namespace Test
{
class A
{
    public int varOfClassA = 5;

    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Class A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int varOfClassB = 10;

    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am class B");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(a1.varOfClassA);  //prints out "5"
        a1.Display();   //prints out "I am class B" why???
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Because it overrides the implementation.  It's still a `B` object just try `Console.WriteLine(a1.GetType())`,

Comment: If it is a B object why it does not see varOfClassB but method?

Comment: Because the method is defined in `A` and that field is not.  If you create another method that only exists in `B` then you will not see it when deaiing with the `a1` variable.

Comment: [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/polymorphism-in-C-Sharp/) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_polymorphism.htm) talk about what you don't understand.

Comment: Imagine that all cars have horns you can honk.  If I blindfold you and put you in a car and you honk the horn it's going to make the sound for the specific type of car you're in.  Just because you don't know the specific type of car doesn't change how it behaves.  That's the type of idea that creating `virtual` methods and overriding them is meant to model.

Comment: Then if it calls B's Display method always, I do not need to use something like this to call B method right? if(a1 is B) {B b1=(B) a1; a1.Display()}  becaus eit always evaluates to overridden method of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the method `Display()` is declared in `B` as `overrides`.
Every member that overrides a base class member will be executed whether the reference type is of the derived or of the base class.

When you do `A a1 = new B();` what you have is an instance of `B`, not an instance of `A`.
However, since the reference is of type `A`, you can only access whatever methods of `B` that also exists in `A`, either inherited as is or overridden.

As a rule, in such cases, when your code executes a method on `a1`, the method that gets executed is the `B` method, since that's the type of instance you have. However, this rule does have an exception - and that is when instead of `override`, the method in `B` is declared as `new`. In such cases, the method (or property) of `A` is executed, even though your instance is of type `B`:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Class A");
    }

    public int MyIntValue { get{ return 5; } }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am class B");
    }

    public new int MyIntValue { get{ return 5; } }
}
```

Using the above classes:

```
A a1 = new B();

a1.Display(); // Displays "I am class B"
Console.WriteLine(a1.MyIntValue.ToString()); // Displays "5"
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/QWFAV45004)

Comment: thank you so much for the through explanation. I think I get it now.